# phpmyadmin: is there any point using dbconfig-common in installation?

Tags: installation, phpmyadmin

The default Ubuntu phpMyAdmin install asks whether `dbconfig-common` should be used. If you answer Yes, then:

1. the install creates a new (MySQL) user named `phpmyadmin` with the password you supply
2. this user is given rights only to the `phpmyadmin` database (with only usage on everything else)
3. the new user's username and password are stored in `/etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf`, with the passsword in clear

phpMyAdmin is actually installed with `auth_type=cookie`, so it doesn't need any new users. You can log in as any existing MySQL user.

I'm having trouble understanding what the point of `dbconfig-common` actually is. User phpmyadmin doesn't appear to be needed, and only has rights on a database that isn't important to the end-user, and creating a new user increases the attack surface. If I drop the phpmyadmin user from MySQL, it doesn't seem to affect phpmyadmin functionality at all, except that I get a warning (`access denied for user 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost'`).

Is `dbconfig-common` doing something else that's important, or should I try to set up the phpmyadmin config file manually? The current docs appear to be [here](https://docs.openstack.org/ocata/de/install-guide-debconf/debconf/debconf-dbconfig-common.html#), but they don't answer the question.

Comment: It turns out that the installation without `dbconfig-common` is trivial, and seems to have no problems. So, it doesn't look like it does anything useful.